# log4j with netbeans (loggin to a file)

Tags: java, netbeans, log4j

i am trying to setup **log4j to my java web application based on Maven on Netbeans 12.6**
, And i am following this video: [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5mOtPP_M5wA) in this tutorial the logging will be writing into a file.

**But in my case after running the application no log file created**

1. This is my Netbeans setup:
   [image]

   **I will appreciate all your answers**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ALL PROBLEMS SOLVED! For Log4J logging to a file on Netbeans**

**Step 1:** *Import log4j-1.2.17.jar library to your project*
[image]

**Step 2:** *First we need to move the log4.properties to a separate directory that we need to create by our self with the name "src/test/resources". For that, Right click on your main project in my case is "Log4Shell" --> then from the categories choose "Other" --> then chose "Properties File" --> then gave it a name "src/test/resources".*
[image]

**Step 3:** *create a new file properties: Right Click on --> new --> Properties File --> File Name:log4j.properties*
[image]

**Step 4:** *we need to create a javaclass under the Test Package repository*
[image]

**Step 5**: *Time for test: Right click on "NewClass.java"-->Debug Test File. Result OK:*
[image]